# Count clicks on a button to create "Top Event" area

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am working on a Tourism website which displays multiple tours.  I am using WordPress and have created a custom post type called Tours.

Inside every tour is a Book Now button which is created as a custom meta box.  The Book Now button contains a link to a Third Party Booking System.

What I am looking to do is create a field on the homepage to show the most popular tour of the week.  This will be judged by the number of clicks on the Book Now button inside each tour.

So, anytime a user clicks Book Now for a certain tour in the week, a count will be set to that tour and the tour with the highest number over a week, sits as a link on the homepage.

How to get this working via JavaScript or PHP?

Answer (score 1):

fire click event on `Book Now` button using jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#booknow").click(function(){
          $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
              data: { action: "countaddone", postId: "1" }
          });
      });
  });
```

now create function into your theme functions.php file like.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_countaddone', 'my_countlogin');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_countaddone', 'my_countlogin');

function my_countlogin(){
     $postid = $_POST['postId'];
     $getcount = get_post_meta($postid,'_my_meta_getcount');
     $count = $getcount[0] + 1;
     update_post_meta($postid,'_my_meta_getcount',$count);
}
```

get how many click on button using this code.

```
 $getcount = get_post_meta($postid,'_my_meta_getcount');
```

Comment: Thank you renishkunt, once I have tested this out, I will come back and let you know how it has worked out for me!

Comment: This way is shorter: `<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>`. And, if the meta field is unique, then add true to `get_post_meta(ID,NAME, true)`, so you don't need `[0]` on `$getcount`.

Answer (score 0):

Each link should have a class and unique identifier

```
<a href="/some/trip/package-A" class="countable" data-id="package-A">Click</a>
```

With jquery on the javascript side, you bind to the `click` event of your link.

```
$('a.countable').click(function() {
     // get our trip identifier
     var identifier = $(this).attr('data-id');
     // ajax call to increment counter
     jQuery.post(
            '/counter.php',
            {track_id: identifier}
        );
    }
});
```

counter.php then received track_id as a $_POST variable and increments your counter somewhere (database / redis / etc..) by calling increment_counter(). You'll also need functionality to report the most popular by week / month / day / etc back out from your datastore.  Since this can be data intensive, its best to do that via a cron script that generates the final output instead of doing that on every page request. At worst, you should cache the "Top X" results for some time (an hour, six hours, a day?).

```
 <?php
 // assumes integer ids, filter inputs appropriately
 $identifier = (int) $_POST['track_id']; 

 if (!empty($identifier)) {
      increment_counter($identifier);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer Oscar, I will try this out and come back and let you know if it has worked for me!